# Angular - ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable

Tags: angular

I have this code in Angular-11. I have been battling with this bug for some time now.:

```js
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  form!: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  separateDialCode = true;
  SearchCountryField = SearchCountryField;
  CountryISO = [];
  PhoneNumberFormat = PhoneNumberFormat;
  preferredCountries = [];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      last_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      mobile_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      confirm_password: ['', [Validators.required]],
      terms: [false, [Validators.requiredTrue]]
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    const formData = this.form.getRawValue();

    const data = {
      first_name: formData.first_name,
      last_name: formData.last_name,
      mobile_number: formData.mobile_number,
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password,
      confirm_password: formData.confirm_password,
      terms: formData.terms
    };

    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    return this.api.post('auth/signup', data, header).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the Angular HTML component that utilize the validation. I have used reactive form. Then the HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" class="form-signin" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" formControlName="first_name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.first_name.errors }">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.first_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.first_name.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.first_name.errors.maxlength">First Name cannot be more than 50 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <ngx-intl-tel-input [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.mobile_number.errors }" [cssClass]="'form-control mb-3'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" [value]="'+234 8077667755'" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
            [enablePlaceholder]="true" name="mobile_number" formControlName="mobile_number" [phoneValidation]="false" name="mobile_number" id="phoneNumber" formControlName="mobile_number">
          </ngx-intl-tel-input>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.mobile_number.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.mobile_number.errors.required">Mobile Number is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.mobile_number.errors.maxlength">Mobile Number cannot be more than 15 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" name="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="last_name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.last_name.errors }">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.last_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.last_name.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.last_name.errors.maxlength">Last Name cannot be more than 50 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@email.com" formControlName="email" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <input type="password" name="confirm_password" formControlName="confirm_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Re enter Password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.confirm_password.errors }">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.confirm_password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.confirm_password.errors.required">Confirm Password is required</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="icheck-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" id="agreeTerms" name="terms" formControlName="terms" value="agree" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.terms.errors }">
        <label for="agreeTerms">
                 I agree with the <a href="#">terms</a>
                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
</form>
```

When I tried to serve it, I got this error on console.log:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
at toObservable (forms.js:791)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at FormControl._composedAsyncValidatorFn (forms.js:858)
at FormControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:2358)
at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2332)
at FormControl.setValue (forms.js:2738)
at updateControl (forms.js:1677)
at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.js:1662)
at DefaultValueAccessor._handleInput (forms.js:250)
at DefaultValueAccessor_input_HostBindingHandler (forms.js:265)
```

I can't even locate the error. How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: terms: [false, [Validators.requiredTrue]]
I guess the above line of code is culprit, is it typo or your customized validator?

Comment: @ammadhassan - How do I resolve it?

Comment: terms: [false, [Validators.required]]

Comment: @ammadhassan - I tried that, but not resolved

Comment: You don't have to put array around single validators;
terms: [false, [Validators.required]] it should be like this;
terms: [false, Validators.required]

Comment: @ammadhassan - I've done that, but still the same error. It's just too strange and not even showing the precise error